# JButton needs to be clicked twice after JDialog

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

I've been struggling with some problem while creating my app based on Swing. I have a main JFrame which consists of:

1. JMenu
2. JPanel containing a JButton and a JLabel

JButton is linked with ActionListener. Clicking JMenu (MenuListener) brings up a JDialog with some form. The problem is, when the JDialog is closed (it doesn't make difference whether I do it with dispose() or rather showVisible(false)) I need to click the JButton two times before it triggers for the first time. From now it normally works with one click.

Every time the JDialog is in front, the problem appears.

PS. The JDialog is set to be modal, with JFrame as parent.

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help you based on the information provided. You've got a bug in your code, and will need to isolate it via debugging before we can begin to be able to help you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a focus issue.

The first click restores focus to the app and the second clicks the button. Typically, I have seen this when the JDialog has the wrong parent and focus can not be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers.

I have considered posting some code, but it involves 4 classes so will be quite long.

I have also tried things with focus before, but nothing helped. What is interesting: if I display the JDialog by `new myDialog.showVisible(true)` it behaves like I've described. But if I use construction like this:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new JDialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

it closes normally and parent frame doesn't need to be clicked before responding, but on the other hand the displayed Dialog needs so. Additonally, what I do not understand, after opening the Dialog cursor is placed in the text field and I can write normally, but to click some button on it I must click once on the Dialog, only second and next clicks behave like I want to.

PS. Closing the dialog like in the second included example changes nothing.